# Python Pandas Sort DataFrame by Duplicate Rows

Tags: python, pandas

What is the nicest way to see which rows are duplicated in DataFrame with the duplicate rows sorted and stacked on top of each other? I know I can filter for duplicates with `df.duplicated()` or something like `df[df.duplicated()==True]` but need to be able to produce a dataframe with the duplicates and then sort them to show both records in the Dataframe. I also do not need to use a col subset argument for this. -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to sort by all columns. Not sure how efficient that is though.

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame (np.random.randint (100,size=(3,3)), columns= list('ABC'))

In [21]: df = df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
    A   B   C
0  23  71  65
1  63   0  47
2  47  13  44
3  23  71  65
4  63   0  47
5  47  13  44

In [23]: df.sort(df.columns.tolist())
Out[23]: 
    A   B   C
0  23  71  65
3  23  71  65
2  47  13  44
5  47  13  44
1  63   0  47
4  63   0  47
```

Comment: Thanks. For some weird reason that didn't work. I keep checking that I have dupes by using df.duplicated().value_counts() and it does show as many rows as True but then when I apply `df.sort(df.columns.tolist())` as you suggest, it still is not sorting all of the duplicated rows.